# Handling percent-sign (%) in Django blocktrans tags

Tags: django, localization, escaping

I'm currently localizing my Django app. All other translations work fine except percent-sign inside blocktrans tags.

In my template I have `{% blocktrans %}Original % blocktrans{endblocktrans %}`.

`django-admin makemessages` produces this in django.po:

```
#: templates/index.html:78
#, python-format
msgid "Original %% blocktrans"
msgstr ""
```

I update that to `msgstr "Translated %% blocktrans"`, run `django-admin compilemessages`, restart dev server and refresh the page, but I still see `Original % blocktrans` in the output. Other translations are shown properly.

For reference, `{% trans "Original % trans" %}` also works ok. After makemessages and translation I have:

```
#: templates/index.html:72
msgid "Original % trans"
msgstr "Translated % trans"
```

This works as expected - translated version is shown.

I must use blocktrans because I also need to embed variables to the strings. I'm using Django 1.2.5.

How can I make blocktrans work with percent-signs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't find a real solution to the problem, so I used a workaround: create a constant PERCENT_SIGN = u'%' and use that as {{ PERCENT_SIGN }} inside blocktrans-blocks.

Comment: What about using html entity &#37; ?

Comment: That would probably work, but I think it would be even more confusing to the translator than `{{ PERCENT_SIGN }}`, though shorter. Also, I'm using this for plain text email templates, so the entity is a no-go.

Comment: Right.. Well, the best solution would be to fix `blocktrans` in Django trunk :)

Comment: Or just like that: {% blocktrans with percent="%" %} This is 100{{ percent }} working! {% endblocktrans %}

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4982) - it's not a solution, but it sheds light on what's going on

Answer (score 2):

Another ticket has been opened for this particular issue, with a patch that fixes it. Hopefully it will be fixed for Django 1.4.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16721

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/translation/#troubleshooting-gettext-incorrectly-detects-python-format-in-strings-with-percent-signs) mention this problem. It looks like you must have `%%` also in the translated phrase. Hence `# xgettext:no-python-format` is a bit useless, since the translators must be aware of that anyway. Using `%%` everywhere works.