# Django translations block not translated

Tags: django, templates, translation, percentage, django-i18n

I have a Django 1.6 template with the following content (base language is german, the translation is in english):

```
{% trans "My App" as appname %}
{% blocktrans with appname=appname %}Garantie: '{{ appname }}' ist 100%% gratis!{% endblocktrans %}
{% trans "Hallo {firstWordInName}," %}
```

When generating the .po files it looks like that:

```
msgid "Garantie: '%(appname)s' ist 100%% gratis!"
msgstr "We assure you: '%(appname)s' is 100%% free of charge!"

msgid "Hallo {firstWordInName},"
msgstr "Hello {firstWordInName},"
```

But when rendering the django template only the string "Hallo {firstWordInName}," is translated. The other one keeps being german. What is the reason for that? I think django translations for strings with percentage signs are really broken....

Thanks in advance! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Thanks Selcuk for reply, but its not a duplicate. I already use two percent signs in the source language in order to make it work.

Comment: See the accepted answer of that question. Did you try the workaroud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple solution, maybe even better than the one suggested in [Handling percent-sign (%) in Django blocktrans tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448207/handling-percent-sign-in-django-blocktrans-tags)

```
{% blocktrans with percent="%" %} This is 100{{ percent }} working! {% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: Brillinat!! Thank you! :)